# When I click on different menus in the bottom menu, a new page does not open

Tags: java, android

I was making a bottom menu for my application, but I had a problem with the switch case codes, so I made my codes if else.  The problem is gone, but when I click on the menus at the bottom, the screen I want does not open.

I created a menu at the bottom for my application and wanted it to switch to different screens when I click on the menus, but when I click on the menus, it stays on the same screen.

Comment: Can you share your code so that we can help identify what might be the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.